# How to invoke a rails sweeper in this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, sweeper

As you can see from code below. I am caching the `show` action. I also have the following method in the show action `View.create_for(@song)`.

I would like to make it so, when `View.create_for(@song)` is called, it clears out the respective cache.

How would I go about this? Do I have to manually invoke the rails sweeper in the `View` model? If so, how?

My controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :show, :cache_path => (proc do 
    song_path(params[:id], :user_id => user_signed_in? ? current_user.id : nil)
  end)

  # I tried with the following line, but this is not what I want. I only want to call the sweeper when `View.create_for(@song)` is called:
  # cache_sweeper :views_sweeper, :only => [:show]

  def show
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    View.create_for(@song)
  end
end
```

My Sweeper:

```
class SongsSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Song

  def after_save(song)
    expire_fragment(/songs\/#{song.id}\/.*?/)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be referring to the songs_sweeper, not the views_sweeper:

```
cache_sweeper :songs_sweeper, :only => [:show]
```

I'm not sure of your requirements, but you could also be more specific in your SongsSweeper by changing after_save to after_create:

```
class SongsSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Song

  def after_create(song)
    expire_fragment(/songs\/#{song.id}\/.*?/)
  end
end
```